# Store info from .txt file as variables

Tags: java, variables, bufferedreader

I am trying to get my code to read from a text file and store what's in it as variables..strings and doubles...to use later. I have no problem getting it to return the info.

This is what's in the .txt file:

```
circle 5
triangle 3
square 10
sphere 5
cube 4
tetrahedron 8
```

and for my code I have:

```
            BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "src/Data.txt"));

            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                // read next line
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: is your file format fixed? why not using standard properties file and related java tools to read it? `Properties prop` example https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to do with the result after that. It helps us to provide you with other alternative ways to get what you want to achieve.

Comment: i need to access the numerical values to calculate area of the shapes listed in the text file. The calculations take place in another class, so I need to be able to work with those values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your text contents in a hash map, in the following code, I name it "vars". The hashMap vars contains your variables as key,value pairs.
If you need to get the value of any of the variables, you simple write:

```
    vars.get(key);
```

so for example to get the value of circle, you write:

```
     vars.get("circle");
```

This is your code after modifying it with a hashmap to store variables.

```
    BufferedReader reader;
    HashMap<String,Double> vars = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "src/Data.txt"));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            String[] lineVars = line.split(" ");
            vars.put(lineVars[0],Double.parseDouble(lineVars[1]));
            // read next line
            line = reader.readLine();

        }
        reader.close();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: how can I access this if I want to use it in another class?

Comment: One of two things, either change the function that reads the file to return the hash map, or create a property in the class for the hash map and add a getter for it to be accessible from other classes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to construct a variable name. You can't read "circle" and assign that as a variable name. You can store these as a [key,value] pair using a `HashMap<String,Double>` to store them as a pair.

Answer (score 0):

The first part would be to split the lines, using `String.split`, to separate variable name and value. If you know in advance which variables you expect in the text file, you can declare those variables and use a `switch` statement to decide which variable the read name corresponds to, and assign the value accordingly. Otherwise, a `HashMap` or something similar could be used to store the names and values found in the file.